# Spring Boot Security Login (v4)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, spring-boot

I've been racking my brain on this one for a couple days now. Backstory is, I'm using Spring Boot with `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency for the security aspect. I'm trying to build a REST Web Service that should only reply with JSON (or XML if I decide to implement that as well). I can return resources and my URI's work fine, so no problem there. I even have json object authentication on the security.

So Here's my problem. When an unauthorized user tries to access a restricted resource, Spring Security delivers a login page (HTML). This is problematic. I just want it to return a 401 and possibly a JSON error object of my choosing. Same with successful logins. I don't want it to redirect. And especially not a pre-made HTML page.

I have looked up tutorials and everyone mentions using `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and the like for controlling the flow. BUT! I don't have that. Apparently that method doesn't exist anymore for HttpSecurity class. Anyone have the answer? Here's the relevant code, I'll supply more if you need it.

```
    @Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private JsonAuthenticationFilter authFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        authFilter = new JsonAuthenticationFilter();
        authFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login","POST"));
        authFilter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManagerBean());

        httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .failureUrl("/error")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/version")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

And the maven dependencies...

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When an un-authorized user tries to access a restricted resource,
>   Spring Security delivers a login page (HTML). This is problematic. I
>   just want it to return a 401 and possibly a JSON error object of my
>   choosing

If you don't want the `Form Login`, just disable it in your `SecurityConfiguration`. In order to do that, replace this piece of configuration:

```
formLogin()
        .permitAll()
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .failureUrl("/error")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
```

With:

```
formLogin()
        .disable();
```

Or you can just throw away the `formLogin` part.

> BUT! I don't have that. Apparently that method doesn't exist anymore
>   for HttpSecurity class. Anyone have the answer?

It's under `exceptionHandling`:

```
http.exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(yourEntryPoint)
```

Comment: Will disabling the formLogin block get rid of the processing url? I like that spring just injects the json object POST-ed to /login automatically.

Comment: HOLY C*** THAT WORKED. Is this just not documented right? Or do I just suck at reading docs?

Comment: It's documented but not in spring boot's documentation. You should read spring security reference documentation which is very thorough

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: If I could bother you one last second to point me in the right direction for over-riding the success and failure handlers for login and logout. I'm not using XML and those are the resources I'm finding. What I mean is, the docs mention AuthenticationSuccessHandler, but I can't find where to put that either.

Comment: Nevermind, found it. Thanks for the help. And for anyone else looking for it now, it's was under my AuthenticationFilter.